# Neutron port create

Tags: openstack

I am using neutron openvswitch plugin. I successfully created a port using neutron port-create, but I do not see the newly created port when I do 'ovs-vsctl show'.
Is it that the port created is just a logical entity that just exists only in DB and only when a VM is launched It is created in openvswitch?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no one from openstack is active here. And also there were a lot a places to ask questions regarding neutron and openstack. I posted my question to openstack mailing list and found that port-create only create a port in db. I am still tracking the issue in the below link so if any one is curious please visit [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/neutron/+question/241870).